# Playing sound on a Nao Robot with python

Tags: nao-robot

How can we play a sound on the Nao robot using python and naoqisdk.
The wav file should be placed on the NAO

error :

> can't load file is popping up each time we start the script

Comment: what script is started?

Comment: Same comments, as often in stack overflow: if you don't post the script, we can't help you easily...

Comment: Same case for me.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way is to create a proxy to ALAudioPlayer then calling some of the module's method, as explained in the documentation:
http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-1/naoqi/audio/alaudioplayer.html#alaudioplayer

For sure, all files need to be present in the robot to be played.